# Integration on SO(3)

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, vector-fields

Let $R\in SO(3)$, and $\widehat \Omega \in \mathfrak{se}(3)$, where $SO(3)$ is the special orthogonal Lie group, and $\mathfrak{se}(3)$ the corresponding Lie algebra. The "hat" operator $\widehat{\cdot}: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathfrak{se}(3)$. Let $u\in\mathbb{R}^3$ be a known control input. I want to simulate the following system in some software environment such as Matlab:
$$
\dot R(t) = R(t)\widehat{\Omega}(t)\\
\dot \Omega(t) = u(t).
$$
Clearly, the first equation is not defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and we cannot use naive integration techniques such as Newton's forward or backward method to integrate the given differential equations, i.e., $R(t+1) = R(t) + dt(R(t)\widehat{\Omega}(t))$, for some small discretization step $dt$. However, we know that the solution of the first differential equation in closed form is $R(t+1) = R(t)exp(dt\widehat{\Omega}(t))$.

Here is my question: can I use the following two equations to integrate the above system without going into the details of integration on manifolds, such as the one mentioned in [1]?
$$
R(t+1) = R(t)exp(dt\widehat{\Omega}(t))\\
\Omega(t+1) = \Omega(t) + dt(u(t)).
$$

Thanks!

References:

1. https://na.math.kit.edu/marlis/download/meetings/08Oberwolfach/Lie_group.pdf

Comment: You might want to try the magic words 'quaternion differentiation' — this particular special case has gotten a lot of study because of the applications to both dynamics and graphics and games, and IIRC there are various numeric solutions available. One can run Newton iteration and then 'project' back to the manifold for first-order accuracy, but there are also various techniques that can give better accuracy and or directly conserve length.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You are right, there are lot of geometric numeric integration methods out there, but the question is do we need to use those "fancy" methods in this particular case because we know the solution of the ODE in closed form? Moreover, I don't get it why we need a "projection back on the manifold" step? The equation $R(t+1) = R(t)exp(dt(\widehat{\Omega}(t)))$ is invariant, i.e., if $R(t) \in SO(3)$, and $\widehat{\Omega}(t)\in\mathfrak{so}(3)$, then $R(t+1)$ stays on $SO(3)$?

Comment: I just mean that there are methods that combine the 'naive' integration techniques with projecting back onto the manifold to produce valid integrators for the differential equations, so those methods _can_ generally be applied to this sort of problem. Also, your equation isn't quite correct: it should be $R(t+1)=R(t)exp(\int_t^{t+1}\hat{\Omega(t)}dt)$. That said, if you can perform this integral in closed-form, then yes, you should be able to just use the exponential map.